# yield WaitForSeconds broken after dismissing iOS modal (Unity 3D)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, unityscript

My JavaScript calls to `yield WaitForSeconds` do not complete if I have previously viewed an iOS modal such as a Chartboost "More Apps" or a GameCenter Leaderboard.

Code:

```
function GoToScene(){

    GameObject.Find("SceneFader").SendMessage("FadeToBlack");

    GameObject.Find("MenuSounds").SendMessage("Play_select");

    //code does not get past here
    yield WaitForSeconds(0.254);

    //Application.LoadLevel() is never called
    Application.LoadLevel(this.scene);
}
```

Is the modal locking up a needed thread?

Answer (score 2):

The modals were freezing time, I was able to fix it using the following:

```
if (Time.timeScale == 0){
    Time.timeScale = 1;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure that timescale isn't set to 0 at some other place in your code when getting to or returning from background?